# ASP.NET MVC Route enumeration

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC CMS application I have a bunch of normal content display routes and some administration routes (for CRUD actions). I was thinking of building an admin menu with unordered list and list items HTML elements but I want to do it dynamically at runtime. So the app should enumerate all the routes and construct the menu using just the administration ones. The idea is to tell them apart by their name - for instance, all admin routes would start with a word Admin. I will then create a controller action and partial view for rendering the menu.

Is this the right idea of doing it? It does feel like a hack though, using a special word for admin routes and then filter it by that but I have no other idea for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its a hack at all and its actually a great idea.  You give your routes names, why not use them?

This is just convention over configuration.  Make a route name "Admin.ManageProducts" and have your code pick that up.